# How to deploy Keras-yolo model to the web with Flask?

Tags: python, keras, yolo

I'm successfully trained my own dataset using Keras yolov3 Github project [link](https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo3) 
and I've got good predictions:

[image]

[image]

I would like to deploy this model on the web using flask to make it work with a stream or with IP cameras.

I saw many tutorials explains how to do that but, in reality, I did not find what I am looking for.

How can I get started?

Answer (score -1):

You can use flask-restful to design a simple rest API.

You can use `opencv` VideoCapture to grab the video stream and get frames.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Open a sample video available in sample-videos
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture('URL')
```

The client will take an image/ frame, encode it using base64, add other details like height, width, and make a request.

```
import numpy as np 
import base64
import zlib
import requests
import time

t1 = time.time()
for _ in range(1000): # 1000 continuous request

    frame = np.random.randint(0,256, (416,416,3), dtype=np.uint8) # dummy rgb image
    # replace frame with your image


    # compress

    data = frame # zlib.compress(frame)

    data = base64.b64encode(data)


    data_send = data

    #data2 = base64.b64decode(data)

    #data2 = zlib.decompress(data2)


    #fdata = np.frombuffer(data2, dtype=np.uint8)


    r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict", json={'imgb64' : data_send.decode(), 'w': 416, 'h': 416}) 
    # make a post request
    # print the response here
t2 = time.time()

print(t2-t1)
```

Your server will load the darknet model, and when it receives a post request it will simply return the model output.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
import json
import numpy as np
import base64


# compression
import zlib


# load keras model

# load_model('model.h5')

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('imgb64', location='json', help = 'type error')
parser.add_argument('w', type = int, location='json', help = 'type error')
parser.add_argument('h', type = int, location='json', help = 'type error')


class Predict(Resource):
    def post(self):
        request.get_json(force=True)
        data = parser.parse_args()

        if data['imgb64'] == "":
            return {
                    'data':'',
                    'message':'No file found',
                    'status':'error'
                    }

        img = data['imgb64']
        w = data['w']
        h = data['h']

        data2 = img.encode()
        data2 = base64.b64decode(data2)

        #data2 = zlib.decompress(data2)

        fdata = np.frombuffer(data2, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(w, h, -1)

        # do model inference here

        if img:

            return json.dumps({
                    'mean': np.mean(fdata),
                    'channel': fdata.shape[-1], 
                    'message':'darknet processed',
                    'status':'success'
                    })
        return {
                'data':'',
                'message':'Something when wrong',
                'status':'error'
                }


api.add_resource(Predict,'/predict')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host = '0.0.0.0', port = 5000, threaded=True)
```

In the `# do model inference here part`, just use your `detect`/`predict` function.

If you want to use native darknet, https://github.com/zabir-nabil/tf-model-server4-yolov3

If you want to use gRPC instead of REST, https://github.com/zabir-nabil/simple-gRPC

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the model of the output is a Keras model ( .h5 ) and I would like to make this model work on stream web using flask.

Comment: 1. yes just use model.predict inside POST method. What do you mean by the stream? You can use cv2VideoCapture with the live url.

Comment: Sorry my friend, but in the second script you wrote, you have loaded a yolov3 model, however, I have a Keras model not a yolov3 model ( .cfg and .weights )

Comment: Your code worked with a yolov3 model ( .cfg and .weights output ) and the project that I've worked output a Keras Model with extension .h5, I have made a referred link to the based project. I have idea how to convert TensorFlow from ckpt to PB ( freeze model ) and I have worked on many projects like this but I didn't have any idea how to put a Keras model on the web.

Comment: Update your code means that you have posted an answer contains an incorrect line ( load your model )

Comment: Don't use links. They are volatile. Which line is incorrect can you mention, please? Also, you mean the comment? Do you know what comments are used usually?

Comment: You have changed `load model from Yolo model` to `load a model from Keras model` in the second code